# I am not able to save data to my sql database from c# app no errors

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am not able to save data to my sql database from c# app its not even giving me any errors. Am I missing something. Its a simple script which will pick up user input from Textbox and check box inserting it into SQL database.
Here is my script.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;


namespace Kaizen_Tracking_System_V1
{
public partial class Individual : Form
{
    SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Asus\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Kaizen Tracking System V1\Kaizen Tracking System V1\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

    public Individual()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Individual_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cmd.Connection = cn;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (logTxtBox.Text != "" & lnameTextBox.Text != "" & fnameTextBox.Text != "" & depCheckBox1.Text != "" & DepCheckBox2.Text != "" & depCheckBox3.Text != "" & depCheckBox4.Text != "" & locationComboBox1.Text != "" & processTextBox.Text != "" & typeTextBox.Text != "" & odgrecdataTextBox.Text != "" & kimpdateTextBox.Text != "" & cipaTextBox.Text != "" & cspmTextBox.Text != "" & rewardgivenTextBox.Text != "" & rcppTextBox.Text != "" & kvdTextBox.Text != "" & ylocationTextBox.Text != "" & detailRichTextBox1.Text != "")
        {
            cn.Open();
            cmd.CommandText = "insert into kaizentracker (lognum,lname,fname,dept,location,process,type,odgrecdate,kimpdate,cipa,cspm,rewardgiven,rcpp,kverifieddate,ylocation,details) values ('" + logTxtBox.Text + "' , '" + lnameTextBox.Text + "' , '" + fnameTextBox.Text + "' , '" + depCheckBox1.Text + "' , '" + DepCheckBox2.Text + "' , '" + depCheckBox3.Text + "' ,'" + depCheckBox4.Text + "' , '" + locationComboBox1.Text + "' , '" + processTextBox.Text + "' , '" + typeTextBox.Text + "' , '" + odgrecdataTextBox.Text + "' , '" + kimpdateTextBox.Text + "' , '" + cipaTextBox.Text + "' , '" + cspmTextBox.Text + "' , '" + rewardgivenTextBox.Text + "' , '" + rcppTextBox.Text + "' , '" + kvdTextBox.Text + "' , '" + ylocationTextBox.Text + "' , '" + detailRichTextBox1.Text + "') ";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cmd.Clone();
            MessageBox.Show("Data Saved");
            cn.Close();
            logTxtBox.Text = "";
            lnameTextBox.Text = "";
            fnameTextBox.Text = "";
            depCheckBox1.Text = "";
            DepCheckBox2.Text = "";
            depCheckBox3.Text = "";
            depCheckBox4.Text = "";
            locationComboBox1.Text = "";
            processTextBox.Text = "";
            typeTextBox.Text = "";
            odgrecdataTextBox.Text = "";
            kimpdateTextBox.Text = "";
            cipaTextBox.Text = "";
            cspmTextBox.Text = "";
            rewardgivenTextBox.Text = "";
            rcppTextBox.Text = "";
            kvdTextBox.Text = "";
            ylocationTextBox.Text = "";
            detailRichTextBox1.Text = "";
        }
    }
}         
}
```

Comment: **warning** your code is extremely vulnerable to sql injection attacks!

Comment: You need to wrap your code in a `try-catch` block or any exceptions (errors) that are thrown will not be caught. You also need to call `.Dispose()` on your `Connection` object or wrap it in a `using` block.

Comment: I would switch to parameterized queries first, then see if the problem goes away.  You need to do this regardless.

Comment: Agreed with commenters saying to change it to parameterised queries. better yet is to used SPROCS (stored procedures). also MessageBox.Show() will NOT work in ASP.NET apps nor is it intended on using it like this.

Comment: @Ahmedilyas Stored Procedures isn't necessarily a requirement here, especially if the OP wanted to switch to an ORM.  Let's learn to walk before we run :P

Comment: Also, this is a minor quibble: you really shouldn't include the "version" identifier in your namespace.  That belongs in the project settings area.

Answer (score 7):

`Initial catalog` is missing in the connection string. you should mention your database name there.

```
@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Asus\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Kaizen Tracking System V1\Kaizen Tracking System V1\Database1.mdf;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase; Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
```

Answer (score 3):

> 1.  use double && symbol instead of single & in your if conditional block

**Replace this :**

```
if (logTxtBox.Text != "" & lnameTextBox.Text != "" & fnameTextBox.Text != "" & depCheckBox1.Text != "" & DepCheckBox2.Text != "" & depCheckBox3.Text != "" & depCheckBox4.Text != "" & locationComboBox1.Text != "" & processTextBox.Text != "" & typeTextBox.Text != "" & odgrecdataTextBox.Text != "" & kimpdateTextBox.Text != "" & cipaTextBox.Text != "" & cspmTextBox.Text != "" & rewardgivenTextBox.Text != "" & rcppTextBox.Text != "" & kvdTextBox.Text != "" & ylocationTextBox.Text != "" & detailRichTextBox1.Text != "")
```

**with following :**

```
if (logTxtBox.Text != "" && lnameTextBox.Text != "" && fnameTextBox.Text != "" && depCheckBox1.Text != "" && DepCheckBox2.Text != "" && depCheckBox3.Text != "" && depCheckBox4.Text != "" && locationComboBox1.Text != "" && processTextBox.Text != "" && typeTextBox.Text != "" && odgrecdataTextBox.Text != "" && kimpdateTextBox.Text != "" && cipaTextBox.Text != "" && cspmTextBox.Text != "" && rewardgivenTextBox.Text != "" && rcppTextBox.Text != "" && kvdTextBox.Text != "" && ylocationTextBox.Text != "" && detailRichTextBox1.Text != "")
```

> **2.You are trying to insert more values into table than specified in query.**

*you have specified that 16 values you are going to insert into table as below:*

```
"insert into kaizentracker(lognum,lname,fname,dept,location,process,type,odgrecdate,kimpdate,cipa,cspm,rewardgiven,rcpp,kverifieddate,ylocation,details)"
```

*but you are inserting 19 values as below:*

```
 values ('" + logTxtBox.Text + "' , '" + lnameTextBox.Text + "' , '" + fnameTextBox.Text + "' , '" + depCheckBox1.Text + "' , '" + DepCheckBox2.Text + "' , '" + depCheckBox3.Text + "' ,'" + depCheckBox4.Text + "' , '" + locationComboBox1.Text + "' , '" + processTextBox.Text + "' , '" + typeTextBox.Text + "' , '" + odgrecdataTextBox.Text + "' , '" + kimpdateTextBox.Text + "' , '" + cipaTextBox.Text + "' , '" + cspmTextBox.Text + "' , '" + rewardgivenTextBox.Text + "' , '" + rcppTextBox.Text + "' , '" + kvdTextBox.Text + "' , '" + ylocationTextBox.Text + "' , '" + detailRichTextBox1.Text + "') ";
```

> **3.You are missing the Database name in SQL Connection String.**

**Replace this :**

```
SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Asus\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Kaizen Tracking System V1\Kaizen Tracking System V1\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");
```

**With Following :**
for example your database name = **sampledatabase**

```
SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Asus\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Kaizen Tracking System V1\Kaizen Tracking System V1\Database1.mdf;Initial Catalog=sampledatabase;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");
```

> **4.Use Parameterized queries to avoid SQL Injection Attacks:**

Example:

```
string SqlCommand= "INSERT INTO myTable ([param1],[param2])VALUES(@param1,@param2)";

        command.Parameters.Add("@param1", SqlDbType.NVarChar,50);
        command.Parameters.Add("@param2", SqlDbType.NVarChar,50);
        command.Parameters["@param1"].Value = name1;
        command.Parameters["@param2"].Value = name2;
```

> **5.Wrap up your code into try-catch/finally block:**

Example :

```
 try { 
//DB Statements 
} 
finally 
{ 
//handle exceptions and close all open connections
 }
```

> **6.Close your Sql Connection Object at the end of the operation.**

Example:

```
try
{
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString);
connection.Open();
}
finally
{
connection.Close();
}
```

Comment: should be using a `using` block for the connection, no matter what it will be close then. otherwise +1

Comment: @Malachi:Thanks, Yes using block is much better than finally,as itself takes care of closing as soon as using block execution gets  Finished.

Answer (score 0):

The whole *User Instance and AttachDbFileName=* approach is flawed - at best! When running your app in Visual Studio, it will be copying around the `.mdf` file (from your `App_Data` directory to the output directory - typically `.\bin\debug` - where you app runs) and **most likely**, your `INSERT` works just fine - but you're just looking at the **wrong .mdf file** in the end!

If you want to stick with this approach, then try putting a breakpoint on the `myConnection.Close()` call - and then inspect the `.mdf` file with SQL Server Mgmt Studio Express - I'm almost certain your data is there.

The **real solution** in my opinion would be to

1. install SQL Server Express (and you've already done that anyway)
2. install SQL Server Management Studio Express
3. create your database in **SSMS Express**, give it a logical name (e.g. `KaizenDatabase`)
4. connect to it using its logical **database name** (given when you create it on the server) - and don't mess around with physical database files and user instances. In that case, your connection string would be something like:

   ```
   Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=KaizenDatabase;Integrated Security=True
   ```

   and everything else is **exactly** the same as before...